# Shiny output depending on browser

Tags: r, browser, shiny

My shiny app is not working well on internet explorer and I want the app does not appear for this browser.

Do you know any R fuction that I can discover the browser??

Example:

```
if( browser = IE){    
    "use Mozilla, chrome or safari"}    
else{
    run my app}
```

Thanks!

Luis

Answer (score 1):

`session$request` contains a `HTTP_USER_AGENT` value if one is given. You could probably use that to work out what browser is being used:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    textOutput("text")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    myReactives <- reactiveValues(ua = session$request$HTTP_USER_AGENT)
    output$text <- renderText({
      myReactives$ua
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thank you @jdharrison . But do you know if it works on internet? For me it is working just locally, when I deploy it nothing appears.

Comment: By deploy do you mean shinyapps.io? If so I dont know if it would work in this case.

Comment: Yes, I´m using shinyapps.io.